# Match <pre> and </pre> inside a <pre>

Tags: javascript, regex

Impossible looking task. I have a server output that contains dump inside a `<pre>`. Unfortunatelly I happen to dump a file that contains some html tags. I need to convert any inner `</pre>` to HTML entities so that the structire is not broken when I append the data to DOM:

```
   <pre> 
      ...
      echo '<pre>'
      cat gcc.log
      echo '</pre>'
      ...
   </pre>
```

But there's an obvious rule - there will always be a `echo '` before `<pre>` or `</pre>`. It might not be exactly `echo '</pre>` though.

Based on this, I have constructed already quite complex regular expression:

```
   <pre>   - The beginning tag
       ([\s\S]*?) - Any characters including new lines
           (?:(echo[^\n]+) - Echo and anything but new line
               (<pre>|<\/pre>|<\/xmp>|<xmp>)) - The enclosing tags
           ([\s\S]*?) - More random characters
   <\/pre>
```

The problem is, that as soon as there are two `</pre>` in the code, the regexp only matches the first and treats the second as *random characters* - `([\s\S]*?)`.

How can I make regex to first try to match explicit characters and then the `.*?` stuff?

You can try the thing live at [http://regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/bL3eO0)

<sub>Oh, and I can't fix it on server, really</sub>

Comment: Can't you fix the server script, so it dumps something like `echo '<pre>' . html_special_chars($filedump) . '</pre>';`? In short, just escape special characters inside the pre?

Comment: Convert the whole thing, as usual?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't fix the broken output on the server-side. I have stated this in my question already.

Comment: There is a `prde` in the demo, is that a typo?

Comment: I've been breaking and creating the tags to see what happens. It's rather a leftover than a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work (assuming that tags are inside quotes and that quotes are balanced in particular):

```
var html = "<pre>\n      ...\n      echo '<pre>'\n      cat gcc.log\n      echo '</pre>'\n      ...\n</pre>";

html = html.replace(/(<pre[^>]*>)((?:(?=((["'])(?:(?=(\\.|[^\\"']+|(?!\5)["']))\4)*\5|[^'<]+|<(?!\/pre>)))\3)*)<\/pre>/g, 
                    function(_, g1, g2) {
                        g2 = g2.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
                        g2 = g2.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
                        return g1 + g2 + '</pre>';
                    }
                   );

console.log(html);
```

This pattern emulates atomic groups with this trick: `(?>pattern)` => `(?:(?=(pattern))\1)` using the fact the content of a lookahead is naturally atomic, to avoid catastrophic backtrackings.

Comment: Upvoting this cool trick! :) Did you invent it, or did you come across it somewhere?

Comment: Ah just found it on p. 174 of MRE 3rd ed. Must have forgotten about many cool things, need to reread it. :)

Comment: @zx81: No, I didn't invent it! It is a well know trick (probably from friedl book)

Comment: Very useful, glad to see it in action and hope I'll remember it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a JavaScript compatible regex that matches a PRE element having exactly one nested PRE element (presented in Python free-spacing form with lots of comments so that you can understand how it works):

```py
re_pre_inside_pre = re.compile(r"""
    # Match PRE element containing one nested PRE element.
    (<pre\b[^>]*>)      # $1: Outer PRE start tag.
    (                   # $2: Outer PRE element contents.
      (                 # $3: Stuff from <PRE> to <PRE>.
        [^<]*           # (normal*) Zero or more non-tags.
        (?:             # Begin ((special normal*)*).
          <             # (special) Any other tags,
          (?!\/?pre\b)  # but not a <PRE> or </PRE>.
          [^<]*         # More (normal*).
        )*              # End ((special normal*)*).
      )                 # End $3: Stuff from <PRE> to <PRE>.
      (<pre\b[^>]*>)    # $4: Inner PRE start tag.
      (                 # $5: Inner PRE element contents.
        [^<]*           # (normal*) Zero or more non-tags.
        (?:             # Begin ((special normal*)*).
          <             # (special) Any other tags,
          (?!\/?pre\b)  # but not a <PRE> or </PRE>.
          [^<]*         # More (normal*).
        )*              # End ((special normal*)*).
      )                 # End $5: Inner PRE element contents.
      (</pre\b\s*>)     # $6: Inner PRE end tag.
      (                 # $7: Stuff from </PRE> to </PRE>.
        [^<]*           # (normal*) Zero or more non-tags.
        (?:             # Begin ((special normal*)*).
          <             # (special) Any other tags,
          (?!\/?pre\b)  # but not a <PRE> or </PRE>.
          [^<]*         # More (normal*).
        )*              # End ((special normal*)*).
      )                 # End $7: Stuff from </PRE> to </PRE>.
    )                   # End $2: Outer PRE element contents.
    (</pre\b\s*>)       # $8: Outer PRE end tag.
    """, re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
```

Note that the: `normal* (special normal*)*` parts are unrolled loops - an efficiency technique taken from Jeffrey Friedl's [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124).

Note also the capture groups:
`$1:` - The outer PRE start tag.
`$2:` - The contents of the outer `PRE` element.
`$3:` - Stuff from `<PRE>` to `<PRE>`.
`$4:` - The inner PRE start tag.
`$5:` - The contents of the inner `PRE` element.
`$6:` - The inner PRE end tag.
`$7:` - Stuff from `</PRE>` to `</PRE>`.
`$8:` - The outer PRE end tag.

Here is a tested JavaScript function which utilizes the above regex to convert all the angle brackets within the outer PRE contents (i.e. the contents of group `$2`) into HTML entities:

```js
// Process PRE element containing one nested PRE element.
function processNestedPRE(text) {
    var re_pre_inside_pre = /(<pre\b[^>]*>)(([^<]*(?:<(?!\/?pre\b)[^<]*)*)(<pre\b[^>]*>)([^<]*(?:<(?!\/?pre\b)[^<]*)*)(<\/pre\b\s*>)([^<]*(?:<(?!\/?pre\b)[^<]*)*))(<\/pre\b\s*>)/gi;
    return text.replace(re_pre_inside_pre,
        function(m0, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8){
            // m2 has the outer PRE contents.
            // Convert all its <> angle brackets to entities:
            m2 = m2.replace(/[<>]/g,
                // Use a literal object for conversion.
                function(n0){ return {'<': '&lt;', '>': '&gt;'}[n0]; });
            // Put humpty dumpty back together again.
            return m1 + m2 + m8;
        });
}
```

It is unknown which parts are in need of entification - this is why I've included all the capture groups so that you can modify the replace function to do just those parts which are required.

Hope this helps.